# Extending MXML component, Ambiguous Reference

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml, mxmlc

I'm having some trouble extending classes in MXML, I will attempt to explain here, but I have also uploaded a [**Sample Flash Builder Project**](https://mega.co.nz/#!O5xSVJoS!MA8Hc2haMfgciAGd5Wd0cRS52sIk1iC9dfZ0O91fePk).

---

Consider that I have 2 classes:

- `game.implementation.base.view.MainView`
- `game.implementation.ipad.view.MainView`

note that they have slightly different package names (one is for ipad).

The idea is that the `ipad` package's classes will extend the classes of the `base` package.

---

Doing as described above produces an error:

> **Ambiguous reference to MainView**. [Generated code (use -keep to save):
>   Path:
>   D:\FlexTests\Tests\bin-debug\generated\game\implementation\ipad\view\MainView-generated.as,
>   Line: 95, Column: 62]

I have reviewed the generated code, the offending function is:

```
_watcherSetupUtil.setup(this,
    function(propertyName:String):* { return target[propertyName]; },
    function(propertyName:String):* { return /** HERE **/ MainView[propertyName]; },
    bindings,
    watchers);
```

---

I have narrowed the problem down, I think it is caused by:

- Extending class having the same name
- Extending class using bindings in the MXML

**Is there a way to fix this without doing either of the above?**

I would prefer not to rename the classes, and obviously removing the bindings is not an option.

Comment: Extending classes that use bindings in MXML should cause no issue.  However, two classes with the same name can cause all sorts of issues.  If I had to guess--and this is just a guess--the ActionScript generated from the MXML is not fully qualifying the class name in some place where the class is referenced; and this is causing the ambiguous reference because it can't tell which class is being referenced.  It could be a compiler bug; albeit I bet the use case for this is low.  Quick Fix: Change the name of "MainView" to "MainViewIPad" or something similar.

Comment: I noticed something after that previous comment I didn't notice; which is the "MainView" reference in your code snippet.  So, I'm sure the problem is the fact that that class name is not fully qualified. Perhaps both classes are referenced/imported in the generated code somehow?

Comment: @Reboog711: Yes it's a bug in the compiler, I found an old bug issue and cloned it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-33580

Comment: I'm glad you have a answer, even if it isn't a solution.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's a bug in the compiler, I found an old bug issue and cloned it:

[FLEX-33580: CLONE - Ambiguous reference when using data binding in inherited class with the same name as base class in a different package](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-33580)

> This only occurs when the:
>
> > (a) Extending class has the same name as base class, but is in a different package .
> >
> > (b) Extending class makes use of data binding.

The workaround is to rename one of the classes.